# Directing to a new route on the basis of response from server in React

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am working in a user authentication project using react-express server . I created a server which sends a confirmation code to the user for creating a new account.However that's not the case if the user enters an email which is already used .So I need to redirect to a new route on the basis of the response of from the server.How should I go from here ownward.

```
import axios from 'axios';
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import'./reset.css'


export default class reset extends Component {
 constructor(){
 super();
 this.state={
 Email:'',
 Response:''
}
this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
}
handleClick(e){
this.setState({
  [e.target.name]:e.target.value
 })
}
handleSubmit(e){
e.preventDefault();
axios.post('http://localhost:5000/resetPassword',{
  Email:this.state.Email
}).then((res)=>{
  if(res.data ==`An email has been sent to ${this.state.Email}`){
   <redirect to ='/home'/>
  }
  else{
  this.setState({
    Email:'',
    Response:res.data
  })
  }
})

}

 render() {
  return (
   <div>
    <div className="Container">
      <div className="subContainer">
        <div className="message">{this.state.Response}</div>
        <p className="notice">Enter your email to reset the password</p>
       <form className="form">
       <input className="takeEmail" type = "email" name="Email" onChange={this.handleClick} value={this.state.Email}placeholder="Enter your email" required/>
       <button type="button" onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Submit</button>
       </form>
      </div>
     </div>      
  </div>
  )
 }
}
```

I just want to redirect to a new route where a user can enter the confirmation code . I simply want a automatic redirection if certain response is obtained.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly. to redirect using `react-router` in javascript parts of code, you should use [history](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/history) object that is in the route component's props (if your component is not connected to `Router` directly, you can use [withRouter](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/withRouter) HOC) instead of using `<Redirect />` component (it is JSX and only related to render part).

like: `this.props.history.push('/route_name', { Email, Response })`

you are also checking email message using double equals. you should change it to `===` (triple equals). also, try to find a better approach to finding out if the request was successful or not.

Comment: didn;t work,it is directing nowhere,I am still in the same route

Comment: you should add a new route to your router and put that route's name in the `history.push`. you also should check response correclty.

Comment: Yeah! I already have that path in my router and I am checking the condition correctly.

Comment: @IcanCode. put a `try...catch` block inside your `handleSubmit` function and check if there is an error. or put your code somewhere I could see

Comment: `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3000/reset/sendCode' (redirected from 'http://localhost:5000/resetPassword') from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`I am getting this error in my console

Comment: @IcanCode then your API result has a `CORS` error and because of this, it doesn't work!
you should add * value to 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in all API requests in your backend.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228991/discussion-between-amirmohammad-moradi-and-icancode).